# Android SQLITE: insertWithOnConflict() duplicates insertion

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to insert list of objects into my SQLite db. If I do query for each object to check if its present, it takes alot of time for long list (20-30sec).

I used function 'insertWithOnConflict()' to do that faster.

I thought that it will try to insert a row and if record with same value of column entered to function already exists, it will just replace its values (like update) otherwise it will insert new row.

But I checked my DB and it is creating duplicated objects. Any solution for this?
Important information `'COLUMN_OBJECT_ID'` is not `'PRIMARY_KEY'`. `'PRIMARY_KEY'` is autoincrement. But `'COLUMN_OBJECT_ID'` has to be unique in this case. So I want to update row with same `'COLUMN_OBJECT_ID'` because data inside can change.

Code:

```
fun saveObjectsToCache(objects: List<Item>) {
        val db = getDb()
        db.transaction {
            objects.forEach {item->
                val cv = ContentValues()
                cv.apply {
                    put(COLUMN_OBJECT_ID, item.id)
                    put(COLUMN_OBJECT_DATA, item.js.toString())
                }
                insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_OBJECT_CACHE, COLUMN_OBJECT_ID, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a UNIQUE constraint for COLUMN_OBJECT_ID?

Comment: No. Only Primary key is marked

Comment: Then there is no conflict when you insert the new rows.

Comment: Should it be like this?
`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_OBJECT_CACHE("
                    + "$COLUMN_ID $INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                    + "$COLUMN_OBJECT_ID $TEXT UNIQUE, "
                    + "$COLUMN_OBJECT_DATA $TEXT)")`

Comment: It could be but I don't see the point of an autoincrement primary key. If COLUMN_OBJECT_ID is unique you can define it to be the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to add a unique constraint on `COLUMN_OBJECT_ID`.
Because of this, there is no conflict when you add a row with the same `COLUMN_OBJECT_ID`.

Make `COLUMN_OBJECT_ID` unique and it should work.

Additionally, if `COLUMN_OBJECT_ID` is unique, and is what you use for checking existing values in the table, you should probably make it the primary key, instead of the auto increment one you are using right now as the primary key.
It will be more efficient both in memory usage, and in performance